# Find best horizontal line for least maximum error

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, optimization

Can someone show me rigorously how to do (2) and (3)?

I don't want to reason about them in a hand-wavey way.

I think the piecewise derivative can be setup like this: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivative+of+-%28max%28%28%7C0-C%7C%2C+%7C40-C%7C%29%29%29+with+respect+to+C

For (2), how do I find the discontinuity at C=20 by hand, instead of Wolfram Alpha?

[image: for lea]

Comment: You are not allowed a discontinuity.  You are required to find the best straight line for each error function.  The process is the same.  Compute the error function as a function of the $m,b$ parameters of the line.  Take the derivative with respect to $m,b$.  Set both derivatives to zero, giving two equations.  Solve for $m,b$.  The problem is that the derivatives may be zero over a range of parameters.  This will not be true for $(1)$, which is one reason we prefer least squares.

Comment: @RossMillikan I am not sure how to deal with the derivatives mechanically over the maximum and absolute value, that is the whole problem. mjw's answer for (2) makes a lot of sense if you graph out the absolute value equations, find the "V" shape that is the maximum, and take the minimum of that. But ideally I would like a non-graphical/generalizable method that works when we have an arbitrary number of absolute value equations.

Comment: There is no $(m,b)$.  The line is $y=C$.  The problem in (1) is to find the least squares solution for horizontal lines.

Answer (score 1):

PART 2:

$$\begin{aligned} 
E_\infty   &= \min \max \left\{ |C|,|C-40| \right\} \\
E_\infty^2 &= \min \max \left\{ C^2,(C-40)^2 \right\} 
\end{aligned}$$

The minimum of the maximum occurs when $C^2=(C-40)^2$.

Thus C=20.

PART 3:

Same idea:

$$E_1 = 9 |C| + |C-40|$$

We could reason that $0 \le C \le 40$, so

$$E_1 = 9C + (40-C) = 40+8C.$$

Thus $C=0.$

Part 1:

You did not ask about Part 1, so my guess is that you've solved it!

$$E_2 = 9C^2 + (40-C)^2$$

We know how to minimize this.

$$C=4.$$

Comment: What's the logic here? Squaring preserves the roots of the absolute value and is easier to differentiate?

Comment: Can you share how you would do (3) as well?

Comment: Well, yes, you don't have to square both of these.  I squared these to determine the solution algebraically, but yes, you can just look at it!  The graphs of $|C|$ and $|C-40|$  intersect where $C=20.$

Comment: The question asks "find the best *horizontal* line."  Yes, if we could take any line, we would have another degree of freedom and could reduce the error.

Comment: I missed the horizontal line in the question.  This is good for $(2)$

Comment: @mjw. Two questions about your solution for part 3. 1) Why must C be between 0 and 40? 2) The derivative of E wrt C is (40+8C)' = 8. Setting this equal to 0 to find the fixed point, we have 8 =0. This is a contradiction. How do you get C=0 from this?

Comment: @user3180, well, we want to minimize the distance to "0" (nine times) and the distance to "40".  If $C<0$, we could always do better by making $C=0$.  This brings us closer to both $40$ and $0$.  Similarly, If $C>40$, lowering to $C=40$ will make $E_1$ smaller.  The reason I wanted to bound $C$ is to remove the absolute value, and make the minimization easier.  We could still solve the problem with the absolute values, just a lot messier.

Comment: You are right, often to minimize a function, we take its derivative.  In this case, we cannot set the derivative equal to zero.   Since we've bounded $0\le C \le 40$, it is natural for the solution to occur at a boundary, in this case $C=0$.